# How to use ndb's OR?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have the following code:

```
employees = Employee.query()
employees = employees.filter(query.OR(Employee.passport_id == passport_id,
  Employee.inn == inn))
employees.order(-Employee.added)
results = employees.fetch(5)
```

But I am getting error:

```
NameError: global name 'query' is not defined
```

Btw, how will it work in case `passport_id is None` and `Employee.passport_id is None`. Will it find such match?

Upd. fixed first problem by adding

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import query
```

Second question remains..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ndb.OR, so you won't need to import the query submodule (you should never have to import that).

If passport_id is a defined property, yes, querying for Employee.passport_id == None will work.  (Be sure to use the '==' operator, not 'is'.)

Comment: Thanks. With regards to the first part of the question - that's strange, since this is what given in the docs - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#nest_and_or

Comment: I've raised separate question about 2nd part - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316077/how-to-avoid-returning-of-none-values-with-gae-ndb