# How to avoid returning of None values with GAE NDB?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have complex NDB query like below:

```
employees = Employee.query(query.OR(Employee.passport_id == passport_id,
   Employee.inn == inn,
   query.AND(Employee.last_name == last_name,
    Employee.region == region,
    Employee.prof_area == prof_area),
   query.AND(Employee.last_name == last_name,
    Employee.first_name == first_name,
    Employee.date_of_birth == date_of_birth)
   ))
```

Currently when database value is `None` and my value is `None`, such entity is returned. How can I avoid that?
I think I can do something like (for each field):

```
if inn is None:
    inn = 'something-I-do-not-expect-in-database'
```

But it doesn't look very good.

Comment: you can also do something like `inn = inn or 'something else'`

Comment: could you use some sentinal value other than None to represent None directly in your query?